# Store error message from a code in a separate table

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I have a cursor loop code where the loop is running for one text column which contains some "insert into some table" code and for few values it is throwing an error because of some syntax related issue. I want to store all error messages in a separate table to validate them.

```
    DECLARE @item NVARCHAR(MAX) 
    DECLARE item_cursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY 
    FOR SELECT [text] from GDQ_RULE_MSTR_copy 
    OPEN item_cursor


    FETCH NEXT FROM item_cursor INTO @item 
    WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
    BEGIN

    EXECUTE sp_executesql @Item
    print @Item
    FETCH NEXT FROM item_cursor INTO @item

    END

    CLOSE item_cursor DEALLOCATE item_cursor
```

I want to save those error messages in a separate table.

I have tried this below query:

```
BEGIN TRY 
DECLARE @item NVARCHAR(MAX) 
DECLARE item_cursor CURSOR FAST_FORWARD READ_ONLY 
FOR SELECT [text] from GDQ_RULE_MSTR_copy 
OPEN item_cursor


FETCH NEXT FROM item_cursor INTO @item 
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN

EXECUTE sp_executesql @Item
print @Item
FETCH NEXT FROM item_cursor INTO @item

END

CLOSE item_cursor DEALLOCATE item_cursor

    -- Table does not exist; object name resolution  
    -- error not caught.  

END TRY  
BEGIN CATCH  
    SELECT   
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber  
       ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage;  
END CATCH
```

But here it is not very clear which line it got stuck and all other details. Could you please help me with that

Comment: Are you really storing SQL statements to run in a table? That's sounds like a major injection issue. :/

Comment: I have tried try/catch but I think it's not working well. can you please help on that

Comment: I have posted my code which I have tried but it's not very detail to understand the error. Please help me with this.

Comment: [ERROR_LINE (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/error-line-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017). If you look at the See Also section, you'll see all the related functions.

Comment: Really, however, this seems like an XY problem. If you're storing SQL to be run in a Table, that suggests a design flaw. And if you aren't sanitising that SQL; it's just a huge injection problem.

Comment: But you never did tell us what the real problem you're trying to solve is here, @Raya. I very much  suggest that you have a big injection issue here. If akGuntuku's answer did resolve the problem, you should be marking it as the solution too.

Comment: I did that..thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you are getting is in your proc which is running in your cursor loop, may be try to CATCH THE EXCEPTION IN YOU PROC and store it in a physical table  as below so whenever you execute cursor code your exceptions will stored in a table and later you can track them.

```
BEGIN CATCH  

insert into  physical_table(errornumber int,errormessgae varchar(2000),ErrorLine int)
    SELECT   
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber  
       ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage
       ,ERROR_LINE() AS ErrorLine


END CATCH
```

or ELSE you can also create physical table in your cursor CATCH BLOCK as below to get which item got exception:

```
BEGIN CATCH  

insert into  physical_table(errornumber int,errormessgae varchar(2000),item datatype)
    SELECT   
        ERROR_NUMBER() AS ErrorNumber  
       ,ERROR_MESSAGE() AS ErrorMessage
       ,@Item
END CATCH
```